# How do I test functions using jest

Tags: javascript, function, jestjs

If I have the following js file how would I test the getTextValue and getRadioValue functions using Jest:

```
function getTextValue(textArea) {
    return document.getElementById(textArea).value;
}


function getRadioValue(radioGroup) {
    .....
    return returnedValue;
}

export default class alpha {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }

    myMethod() {
        const answers = {
            answers: [
                { id: "1", text: getRadioValue("a")},
                { id: "2", text: getTextValue("b")}
            ]
        };
   }
}
```

I'd like my test to be something like:

action: myMethod is called,

expect: getTextValue toHaveReturnedWith(Element)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a test file for exemple alphaTest.spec.js in your test folder:

```
import alpha from '/yourfolder'

describe('Alpha', () => {
     test('getValue should have returned element', () => {
           // act
           alpha.myMethod()

           // assert
           expect(getTextValue).toHaveReturnedWith("b")
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `document` context in the node environment.

You have to use the library which emulates browser functionality and populates all the necessary functions you have like `document.getElementById` etc.

One option is to use [JSDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) and create testing HTML snippet for it.

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const textareaValue = 'My-value';
const dom = new JSDOM(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
 <textarea id="textarea" value="${textareaValue}"></textarea>
</body>
`);

const { document } = dom;

function getTextValue(textArea) {
    return document.getElementById(textArea).value;
}

export default class Alpha {
    myMethod() {
        return { id: 1, text: getTextValue("textarea")};
   }
}

describe('Alpha', () => {
  it('should parse textare value', () => {
    const alpha = new Alpha();
    expect(alpha.myMethod()).toEqual({ 
      id: 1,
      text: textareaValue
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to test complex logic and interaction with different [Browser APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) better to use
[Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), etc. These things run actual browsers while testing but are not really recommended for just unit tests. So, option one, to use JSDOM is recommended for your case.